# Non-exponential functions satisfying $f(ab) = f(a) + f(b)$

Tags: exponential-function, functional-equations, group-homomorphism

If $f:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R^+$ satisfies $f(a+b) = f(a)f(b)$, and if we write $f(1) = B$, then it is fairly straightforward to prove that for any rational number $x \in \mathbb Q$, $f(x) = B^x$.  If in addition we know that $f$ is **continuous**, this can be extended to all $x \in \mathbb R$.

But what if $f$ is **not** continuous?  It seems clear (to me) that a function $\mathbb Q \to \mathbb R, x \mapsto B^x$ can be extended to (for example) $\mathbb R[\sqrt{2}]$ by choosing an arbitrary $r\in\mathbb R$ and mapping $\sqrt{2}\mapsto r$; then for any $a,b\in\mathbb Q$ the functional equation would require that $a+b\sqrt{2} \mapsto B^a r^b$.  Continuing in this fashion we can extend the function to all of $\mathbb R$ by mapping each member of a Hamel basis to any real number we like.

Or can we?  Does the description above oversimplify things?  Are there hidden relations that I have overlooked that constrain things?

Moreover, is it possible to do this so that we end up with a dicontinuous $bijection$ $\mathbb R \to \mathbb R^+$?

Comment: What's the issue? Let $\{e_\alpha\}_\alpha$ be a hamel basis and define $f(\sum_\alpha c_\alpha e_\alpha) = \prod_\alpha f(e_\alpha)^{c_\alpha}$. This is obviously well-defined and you can check it satisfies the functional equation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can define your $f$ using a Hamel basis $B$ of $\mathbb R$ over the rationals $\mathbb Q$ and an arbitrary function $g: B \to \mathbb Q$, so that if $x = \sum_{\beta \in B} c_\beta \beta$ (with finitely many $c_\beta$ nonzero), $f(x) = \exp(\sum_{\beta \in B} c_\beta g(\beta) \beta)$.  If $g(\beta) \ne 0$ for all $\beta \in B$, 
then $f$ is a bijection.